# Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for hide()

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am using angular 11 and I have written test case for open and closed model. I am getting the below Error: how to pass templateRef parameter through spec file.

> `<spyOn>` : could not find an object to spy upon for hide()

HTML:

```html
<button class='btn btn-primary' id="button" (click)="openModal(template)">Add</button>

<button type="button" id="cancel-btn" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary"
                (click)="onDeleteCancel()">
```

Component:

```js
 valModalRef: BsModalRef;

constructor(private modalService: BsModalService)

openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
      const CONFIGFORSMALLMODAL: ModalOptions = { class: CommonConst.MODEL_MD, animated: true, keyboard: false, backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: true };
        this.valModalRef = this.modalService.show(template, CONFIGFORSMALLMODAL);
  }

onDeleteCancel() {
  this.valModalRef.hide();
}
```

Spec:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    window.jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    setTimeout(function () {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(), HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
        declarations: [HomeComponent, DataPoolsComponent],
        providers: [PoolManagerService, CommonService, FormBuilder]
      }).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
        set: {
          entryComponents: [HomeComponent],
        }
      }).compileComponents();
    }, 500);
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataPoolsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    poolService = TestBed.get(PoolManagerService);
    commonService = TestBed.get(CommonService);
    formBuilder = TestBed.get(FormBuilder);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
it('onDeleteCancel', () => {
    spyOn(component.valModalRef, 'hide').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component, 'onDeleteCancel').and.callThrough();
    const openBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#button');
    openBtn.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const cancelBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#cancel-btn');
    cancelBtn.click();
    expect(component.valModalRef.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.valModalRef).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a lot of assumptions, because of the lack of code, but I can only assume you forgot to mock the modalRef in your test, which you inject into your component.

So if your component has the following in the constructor:

```js
constructor(private valModalRef: BsModalRef) {}
```

You need to do the following in your test:

```js
let mockModalRef: BsModalRef;

beforeEach(() => {
  const modalRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('valModalRef', ['hide']);

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ComponentName],
    providers: [{ provide: BsModalRef: useValue: modalRefSpy }]
  });

  mockModalRef = TestBed.inject(BsModalRef) as jasmine.SpyObj<BsModalRef>;
});
```

Then you can use this spy in your tests:

```js
 it('onDeleteCancel', async () => {
    const openBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#button');
    openBtn.click();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    const cancelBtn = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#cancel-btn');
    cancelBtn.click();
    expect(mockModalRef.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Poul kruijt for quick response. I am using constructor(private valModalRef: BsModalRef) {}. I have replaced above code to BsModelRef. Now I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: DInesh, this is because the code to query the rendered HTML executed before the HTML is rendered. `await fixture.whenStable()` or `await fixture.whenRenderingDone()`

Comment: @Dinesh I've updated my answer including the comment from \@IAfanasov

Comment: @PoulKruijt  openBtn executed properly but when cancelBtn line executing. I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'triggerEventHandler' of undefined

Comment: @Dinesh ah alright, that makes more sense :) I've updated my answer

Comment: Really appreciate for your time @PoulKruijt. Please provide me a link related bsModelRef. Something I am missing, I really don't know.  It would be more helpful.

Comment: @Dinesh it would be easier to help if you posted all your code. So a minimal reproduction of your issue